# Previous button in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, button, slider

I want to create a slider in Javascript with two buttons 'Next' and 'Previous'. The next button is working but Previous is not. Here is my code:

```js
let myImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
        let images = ["./img/th01.jpg", "./img/th02.jpg", "./img/th03.jpg", "./img/th04.jpg", "./img/th05.jpg"];
        let imageIndex = 1;
        function next(){
            myImage.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);
            imageIndex++;
            if (imageIndex >= images.length) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        function previous(){
            myImage.setAttribute('src', images[imageIndex]);
            imageIndex--;
            if (imageIndex <= 0) {
                imageIndex = images[imageIndex];
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
        <img src="./img/th01.jpg" id="mainImage">
        <br>
        <br>
        <button onclick="previous()">Previous</button>
        <button onclick="next()">Next</button>
    </div>
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `next` button isn't exactly working either. The problem in both functions is that you're changing the index *after* changing the `src`, so the new `src` will reflect what `imageIndex` was after the *last* button click, not the click that just occurred. (and since `imageIndex` is hard-coded to start at 1, the first click always looks to do what the "Next" button is supposed to do)

Initialize `imageIndex` to 0, and change it *before* setting the `src`.

Also, [don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have a demented scope chain, require global pollution, and have quote escaping issues. Use `addEventListener` instead:

```js
let myImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
let images = ["./img/th01.jpg", "./img/th02.jpg", "./img/th03.jpg", "./img/th04.jpg", "./img/th05.jpg"];
let imageIndex = 0;

const [prev, next] = document.querySelectorAll('button');

next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex === images.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
  myImage.src = images[imageIndex];
});
prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  imageIndex--;
  if (imageIndex === -1) {
    imageIndex = images.length - 1;
  }
  myImage.src = images[imageIndex];
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="./img/th01.jpg" id="mainImage">
  <br>
  <br>
  <button>Previous</button>
  <button>Next</button>
</div>
```